# How to compare and count elements of multiple Streams in Java?

Tags: java, neo4j, java-stream

I have a Stream of Streams containing elements (Nodes).

```
Stream<MyStreams>
```

MyStreams have the type:

```
Stream<Node>
```

So actually Stream of Streams have the type:

```
Stream<Stream<Node>>
```

Multiple MyStreams may contain the same Node. I want to know how often a particular Node is contained in the Streams. The output-class Stream could look like this:

```
public class Output
{
    public int count; //number of appereances of a specific node in all streams
    public int nodeId; // ID of the node

    Output()
    {
     ...
    }

}
```

The final Output-List may be:

```
nodeId    |     count
12        |     7
14        |     5
28        |     4
...       |     ...
```

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

This is what I got so far:

```
public class Correlation {


@Context
public GraphDatabaseService db;

@Context
public Log log;

@Procedure
@Description("xxx")

// Main

public Stream<NeighborNodeStream> analysisNeighbors(    @Name("label") String labelString,
                                                        @Name("key") String key,
                                                        @Name("value") String value)

{       
    Label label = Label.label(labelString);


    // Get Stream of Starting Nodes
    Stream<Node>                myNodes                 = db.findNodes(label, key, value).stream();

    // For every Stating node get Stream of Neighbor nodes
    Stream<NeighborNodeStream>  myNeighborNodeStreams   = myNodes.map(x -> new NeighborNodeStream(x));      


    // ***Nodes count ***


    return myNeighborNodeStreams; 

}

public class NeighborNodeStream
{
    public Stream<Node> neighborNodes;

    public NeighborNodeStream(Node node)
    {           
        Stream<Relationship> relsStream = StreamSupport.stream(node.getRelationships().spliterator(), false);           
        this.neighborNodes = relsStream.map(x -> getRightNode(x, node.getId()));
    }

}

private Node getRightNode(Relationship rel, long nodeId) 
{
    long endId = rel.getEndNode().getId();
    if (endId == nodeId)
        return rel.getStartNode();
    else    
        return rel.getEndNode();
}


}
```

Comment: You have given us a description of the problem and a list of requirements and expected output. What is missing is the code you have written already to try to solve your problem. Have you already tried anything yourself? And if so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I had no idea how to solve it so I started creating Property-Maps for every Node and put them all into one array. It got very confusing and needed endless for-loops to count the number of node appereances in all the streams. I  did not post it on purpose as hoped to find another (more elegant) solution. I'll take any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 List<Output> output = Stream.of(Stream.of(new Node(1), new Node(2)), Stream.of(new Node(2)))
            .flatMap(x -> x)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Node::getNodeId,
                            Collectors.summingInt(n -> 1)),
                    map -> map.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map(e -> new Output(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(output); // [id = 1 count = 1, id = 2 count = 2]
```

Comment: Eugene, thanks a lot for your answer. But to be honest I struggle to understand and implement it, ecpecially the first line. Could you please give me some explanation? I posted my current code in EDIT.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand OP correctly, it should be a simple count-by question:

```
Stream<NeighborNodeStream> nodess = ...;
// key is the Node id, value is the occurrences:
Map<Long, Long> res = nodess.flatMap(s -> s.neighborNodes)
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n.getId(), Collectors.counting()));
```